# How to get Azure FunctionApp list using python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-python-sdk

I am trying to get details of function apps using python SDK and finding suitable client and methods. I can use ResourceManagementClient and get basic info on them but does not get runtime and other details. I can run CLI `az functionapp list` and get all the details. I am looking to do something equivalent using python SDK

Answer (score 1):

Below code will give us the list of function apps with all the details:

Enter your subscription id and resource group to their respective variables.

```
# Import the needed credential and management objects from the libraries.
from types import FunctionType
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
import os

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "SUBSCRIPTION_ID" #Add your subscription ID
resource_group = "RESOURCE_GROUP_ID" #Add your resource group
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_list = resource_client.resources.list()

print(resource_list)
column_width =36
print("Resource".ljust(column_width) + "Type".ljust(column_width)+ "Id".ljust(column_width))
print("-" * (column_width * 2))
for resource in list (resource_list) :
    if (resource.type == "Microsoft.Web/sites" ) and ((resource.kind == "functionapp" ) or (resource.kind == "functionapp,linux" )) :
        print(f"{resource.name:<{column_width}}{resource.type:<{column_width}}{resource.id:<{column_width}}")
```

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-list-resource-groups#3b-list-resources-within-a-specific-resource-group) for adding extra parameters.

**Output information from my testing:**

[image: Output Picture]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WebSiteManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.websitemanagementclient?view=azure-python) class to query more details of your function app.

A WebSiteManagementClient instance can instantiate the [WebAppsOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.v2021_02_01.operations.webappsoperations?view=azure-python) class which will allow you to perform many actions on your function app.

See sample code below that worked for me:

```py
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.web import WebSiteManagementClient

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "SUBSCRIPTION_ID" #Add your subscription ID
resource_group = "RESOURCE_GROUP_ID" #Add your resource group
function_app_name = "FUNCTION_APP_NAME" #Add your function app name

# Create the web management client
web_mgmt_client = WebSiteManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Get function app details
function_app_details = app_service_client.web_apps.get(resource_group, function_app_name)
print(function_app_details)

# Get function app configuration details
function_app_config = app_service_client.web_apps.get_configuration(resource_group, function_app_name)
print(function_app_config)

# List function app application settings
function_app_settings = app_service_client.web_apps.list_application_settings(resource_group, function_app_name)
print(function_app_settings)
```

See [WebAppsOperations methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.v2021_02_01.operations.webappsoperations?view=azure-python#methods) for any other details you need to access.